# When I create a LWRP why is nil my global resource into the Chef resource context

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo, lwrp

The creation of a custom LWRP are reporting that the resource is nil into the Chef's resource context . This was my first step?

```
action :install do
  converge_by "Installing postgresql-#{@new_resource.version}" do    
    execute "sudo apt-get install postgresql-#{@new_resource.version} #{@new_resource.options}" do
      not_if { "dpkg --get-selections | grep postgresql-#{VERSION}" }
    end
    @new_resource.updated_by_last_action(true)
  end
end
```

But, I save the global variable value in other local variable. Like this:

```
action :install do
  converge_by "Installing postgresql-#{@new_resource.version}" do

    VERSION = @new_resource.version
    OPTIONS = @new_resource.options
    execute "sudo apt-get install postgresql-#{VERSION} #{OPTIONS}" do
      not_if { "dpkg --get-selections | grep postgresql-#{VERSION}" }
    end
    @new_resource.updated_by_last_action(true)
  end
end
```

And then, the problem was resolved.

Is there a problem in the Chef resources context with the global variables?

Comment: You don't use converge_by + updated_by_last_action

Answer (score 1):

I found that using `@new_resource` in a sub resource of an LWRP just doesn't work, but using `new_resource` (without the @) works fine.